# Checking if an RSA private key is passphrase protected

Tags: key-management, rsa, asymmetric, openssh, passphrase

I have generated an RSA key-pair on a computer, and I want to check if the RSA private key is encrypted (protected) with a passphrase.

Note that the problem is **not** that I forgot the passphrase, but rather that I want to generate the key-pair again with a passphrase if I did not previously. I am curious about the command (or process) to check that information (not the passphrase itself, but the fact whether that the private key is encrypted with a passphrase).

Comment: I am pretty sure it would ask for the passphrase once you try to use the key. Other than that, I am not sure.

Comment: @PeterHarmann not if the key is automatically added to ssh-agent or something similar on login.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just open it, if it's encrypted it will begin with

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-128-CBC,0F5C7993DCFA4C0962CE249CFD854B91
```

if it is not it will begin directly by the (base64 encoded) key :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
MIICWwIBAAKBgQDNhe+F6Ww2Q9XLLDFJ2s+yp/K/rQn2QMCqT3y0sqS6j+a2T
```

Comment: From the command line, you can view the RSA private key header with the *head* command:  
*$ head ~/etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key*

Comment: @safesploit I'm pretty sure it's not the host key he's worried about, and is that `~` accidental or do you actually have `etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key` in your home directory?

Comment: The tilde is accidental, and I used the host key as an example. I was uncertain how to name the key-pair as Linux based OSs and OS X ("id_25519" and "id_25519.pub") both name the key-pair differently.

Comment: But if it starts with "BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY" it's not as easy. Some versions of ssh-keygen seem to use that string when converting a foreign key. I *think* that if the key starts with "MII" then it's not encrypted in that case.

Comment: @BrianPHuntley: foreign is irrelevant. OpenSSH 6.5 up uses 'new format' if you specify `-o` or automatically for ed25519; 7.8 up uses it for all types unless (for non-ed25519) you specify `-m pem`. The OpenSSH format always begins `b3BlbnNzaC1rZXktdjEAAAAA` and then diverges depending on encryption, and type. The 'legacy' (OpenSSL) unencrypted format does start with `MII` (which is 30 82, the first two octets of all reasonable-sized ASN.1 DER SEQUENCEs, and encrypted does not, but they are also distinguished by the Proc-type and DEK-info lines which are much more obvious.